# Azure Data Factory copy data - cannot convert 'System.String' to target type 'Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.EntityReference'

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am trying to set a lookup field in the copy data action in Azure Data Factory.

The error I'm getting is

```
Failure happened on 'Sink' side. ErrorCode=UserErrorTypeConversionFail,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,
Message=,Source=,''Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=The 
attribute 'ks_supervisor' with value 'E3BEFA28-C7A6-EA11-A812-000D3A1BB8EF' cannot be converted from 
original type 'System.String' to target type 'Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.EntityReference'.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary.DynamicsPlugin,''Type=Sy
stem.InvalidCastException,Message=Specified cast is not 
valid.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary.DynamicsPlugin,''Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Sh
ared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=The attribute 'ks_supervisor' with value 'E3BEFA28-C7A6-EA11-A812-
000D3A1BB8EF' cannot be converted from original type 'System.String' to target type 
'Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.EntityReference'.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary.DynamicsPlugin,''Type=Sy
stem.InvalidCastException,Message=Specified cast is not 
valid.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary.DynamicsPlugin,
```

The key piece is `value 'E3BEFA28-C7A6-EA11-A812-000D3A1BB8EF' cannot be converted from 
original type 'System.String' to target type 'Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.EntityReference'`.

**My question is how do I set a lookup field value in D365/CDS/CRM if it is expecting a value of type EntityReference?**

I have tried the CDS connector, Dynamics 365, and the CRM connector, but all result in an identical error. I have also looked for ways to try converting the source value from a string to a GUID, but I can't find a way and I don't know if that will help since it is a GUID not EntityReference. The source column is from a SQL table of type "uniqueidentifier", but it is projecting automatically to a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to add "@EntityReference" to the destination column name in the column mappings. See the answer provided by MSFT here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/34069/azure-data-factory-copy-data-to-cds-cannot-convert.html?childToView=34732#comment-34732

See the documentation for setting lookup column values here. It also shows how to set a customer column value: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-dynamics-crm-office-365#writing-data-to-lookup-field